# Convert DateTime format in epplus

Tags: c#, epplus

I want to read a column from excel into datatable using epplus but whenever i do I get the time in 24 hour format. I want the time to be in 12 hour format as it is in excel.

I have tried changing the date format of excel to "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" it give me AM/PM but it shows the time in 24 hour format.

```
worksheet.Cells["" + firstRowCell.Address + ":" + 
Regex.Replace(firstRowCell.Address, "[0-9]", "") + "" + 
worksheet.Dimension.Rows].Style.Numberformat.Format =  "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
```

Comment: dont you want capital HH as apposed to hh:mm:ss so HH:mm:ss

Comment: In both the cases either HH or hh it shows 24 hour time.

Comment: by "I get the time in 24 hour format", do you mean you get this from your DB after you stored it there? If so, this is not an EPPlus but an DB issue.

Comment: No, I am reading data from excel and then storing into DataTable, the timespan in excel in 12 hour but when I read it into Datatable it only picks up AM or PM instead of the whole time, then I tried changing the excel number format and by the above format it shows AM/PM but the time is in 24 hour format and I want it in 12 hour format.

Comment: do you want to read from the excel file and save the value as a string in the database as 12 hour format or do you want to get the value from a database and show it as a 12 hour format in excel. Changing the Style Format wont change the underlying value

Comment: It has to be a format string that [Excel supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/custom-date-and-time-formats-for-the-format-function).  So use "am/pm" instead of "tt".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are reading formatted display value and not the underlying cell value. Maybe this will help you I am not sure Excel saves the date and time as a double of the number of days from 1900-01-01 the decimal part is how it determines hours in the day. This number could also be negative or positive so what I have done in the past to get the correct value is to read the cell value and convert that to a DateTime.

```cs
//get the underlying value instead of the display value
var cellValue = worksheet.Cells["" + firstRowCell.Address + ":" + 
Regex.Replace(firstRowCell.Address, "[0-9]", "") + "" + 
worksheet.Dimension.Rows].Value;

var stringValue = $"{cellValue}";

//Now convert the double to a valid DateTime;
DateTime value;
var date = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30);
double doubleValue;

if (double.TryParse(stringValue, out doubleValue) &&
   (doubleValue <= 2958465) &&
   (doubleValue >= -693593))
      value = date.AddDays(doubleValue);
```

Once you have a valid DateTime value you can use ToString to get a proper 12 hour format

```cs
value.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, may be is too late. If the **Excel** underlying cell value type is `double` or a numbers as `string`, what I do is convert using `DateTime.FromOADate(double d)` to `DateTime`.

Example, if the Excel cell in `ws[row, col].Value` (for double type) or `ws[row, col].Text` (for string type), the value is like `43191.256944444444444`. Simply,

```cs
var dt = DateTime.FromOADate(43191.256944444444444)
```

Result,

`4/1/2018 6:10:00 AM`